# Show uniqueness of a point

Tags: functions, roots

I use the banana function $F(x_1,x_2)=(1-x_1)^2+100(x_2-x_1^2)^2$ and I found the minimum point X to be (1,1).

I need to show the uniqueness of that point.  Could you please help me on how to show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give some hints:

First show that the point is a local minimum.

Then prove that the function is strictly convex. (For both points you could use properties of the functions hessian matrix, if you are allowd to do so - but of course these are not the only ways.)

This implies that your local minimum is also a global minimum.

Comment: In order to show that it is a local minimum, do I just need to put it in the second derivative and show that it is less than 0? Is that enough?

Comment: The 'second derivative' here is a $2\times 2$ matrix $H$. And you have to show that it is negative definite, that is $x^tHx>0 \forall x \in \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test

Comment: is there any way to show that it is unique by the normal method, I mean to suppose that there two minimum point X,Y and finally to conclude that they are equal?

Comment: If you know the minimum is at $x$, just plug $x+h$ in the eqaution and show that $F(x+h) > F(x) \forall h \neq 0$.

Comment: I am working with you first comment and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test 
In order to find $f_xy(x,y)$ is it correct to say that it is equal to $\frac{f_xx(x,y)}{f_yy(x,y)}$ ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean: $f_{xx}$ denotes the second derivative in $x$ direction, $f_{xy}$ denotes the derivvative in $y$ direction of the derivative in $x$ direction ( $f_{xy}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}$ )